# How to resolve "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, api

I'm trying to read all values from my json, but I'm receiving this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

What I'm doing wrong?

```
fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "user-key": 'mykey'
            },
            body:               
                'fields id, name, cover.url; where id = 1942;'
        })
            .then(response => response.json())          
            .then((data) => {
                data.array.forEach(element => {
                    console.log(element)
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to resolve “Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined” error

You find the place where `forEach` is called (it should be easy to find since the error message contains the file name and line number, which unfortunately you are keeping from us) and then make sure that whatever you are calling `forEach` on is on object that actually as a `forEach` property; presumably an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

The json response is probably organized differently than you think. It's most likely returning the object you sent in your post request, if it was posted successfully. Which would mean you can't use a forEach function on it directly, but rather on its keys or values, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all.. You are trying to use ForEach on an undefined value.
You're not receiving data as per required from the backend.
The data has to be in specific data structures for you to use .forEach on it.

Check whether what you're receiving is array or not.

For example :-

```
console.log(typeof data.array);
```